# BTLE Corebluetooth iOS Transfer an array

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, btle

I am playing with Apple sample code BTLE_TRANSFER https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/BTLE_Transfer/Introduction/Intro.html
In the sample, an iOS device "A" sends to another iOS device "B" some "text" (NSString) when B (central) subscribe to characteristic of "A" (peripheral).
(The data is cut in pieces then sent by piece until everything is received on the other side)

I modified the code to transfer an image using UIImageJPEGRepresentation method and it is working fine (but takes long when size of the image is over 2 ko)

Now I would like to try to transfer an array of different objects like text, image.

I have tried the code below in the didSubscribeToCharacteristic method (Peripheral Manager side):

```
NSArray *MyArray;
MyArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Text1", @"Text2", nil];
_dataToSend = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:MyArray];
```

where _dataToSend is the NSData that is sent

And the code below in the didUpdateValueForCharacteristic method (central side - peripheral delegate):

```
NSArray *My2Array = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:_dataReceived];
NSLog(@"%@",[My2Array objectAtIndex:1]);
```

where _dataReceived is the NSData received

Each piece is received on the central side but some parts are "null" and when I try to Unarchive the data to nsarray, it says that the data is NULL.

Am I using the wrong method?
Is there any other way to put an nsarray into a nsdata?

Thank you for your help

Jimmy

Comment: Have you kept Apple's code where you deal with the fact that the data may be split into multiple transmissions?

Comment: Hi Paul, Thanks for the reply. Yes I kept everything as it was (including the split part in chunks). I actually succeed with transfering an image using this exact same code apple provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is actually working...I just retype everything from ground
Sorry for bothering